# Avoid buffering in ZMQ for a determined time?

Tags: c++, zeromq

We are reading messages from a Kinect that is broadcasting in ZMQ.

We use more or less the following code:

```
socket_t subscriber_eeg(context, ZMQ_SUB);
subscriber_eeg.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5559");
while(true)
{
Do Random stuff
if (pressedPause)
{
    //shows message
    continue;
}

subscriber.recv(&kinect_msg);
//code to process message
//code to plot the hand movements.
}
```

The objective is to pause the execution of the code on the given event that someone pressed pause. The pause event is running on a thread independently.

Everything works fine, but the problem is that, since ZMQ buffers the messages, it suddenly starts plotting every movement that is captured in the paused state.

Is there a way to tell ZMQ to stop receiving the message in the event of the pause, or to clear the buffer?

Comment: Did you try my proposed solution? I hope it was useful for you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just toggle connection state:

```java
subscriber.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5559");
//do work

//user presses 'Pause'
subscriber.disconnect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5559");

//user un-'Pauses'
subscriber.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5559");
```

I just tested this with separate threads, when the subscriber wakes up, it does not rerieve messages sent during disconnected state.

Comment: Thanks, my quick dirty solution was to keep retrieving messages in the pause step, it was dirty but it worked to certain extent

Comment: I thought you _didn't_ want to retrieve messages in the pause step?

Comment: I don't need them, that's the thing, and I thought it would be more elegant just to pause the process instead of wasting memory reading values that you don't need

Comment: Pausing the thread isn't sufficient as message will accumulate in buffers. You could try setting the `receive` HWM to 0 just after pausing, then setting to a higher value after unpausing. I did, however, try that too (before the above solution), and it had no effect, maybe I was doing something wrong, but disconnect/connect was much simpler. Anyway, hope it helps